# Borrow issue with 'self

Tags: rust

I tried to make the example code as simple as possible

```
struct Level;

pub struct GameManager<'self>{
    lvl: Level,
    actors: ~[Actor<'self>]
}
struct Actor<'self>{
    lvl: &'self Level
}
impl<'self> GameManager <'self> {
    pub fn new() -> GameManager{
        GameManager {lvl: Level,actors: ~[]}
    }
    fn spawn_actor<'r>(&'r self) -> Actor<'r>{
        Actor{lvl: &'r self.lvl}
    }
}
fn main() {
    let mut gm = GameManager::new();

    let mut actor1 = gm.spawn_actor();

    gm.actors.push(actor1);


}
```

Error:

```
/home/maik/source/test.rs:23:4: 23:13 error: cannot borrow `gm.actors` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
/home/maik/source/test.rs:23     gm.actors.push(actor1);
                                 ^~~~~~~~~
/home/maik/source/test.rs:21:21: 21:23 note: second borrow of `gm.actors` occurs here
/home/maik/source/test.rs:21     let mut actor1 = gm.spawn_actor();
```

As you can see I want the GameManager to spawn an actor. A GameManager as a Level and I want all spawned actors to have a reference to the GameManager's Level.

Can someone explain this error to me? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems it is not possible in Rust.

But I found a solution to do this, I just needed to encapsulate a little bit more, like

```
struct Level;
pub struct ActorController{
    lvl: Level
}
pub struct GameManager<'self>{
    actors: ~[Actor<'self>],
    actor_controller: ActorController
}
struct Actor<'self>{
    lvl: &'self Level
}
impl ActorController {
    fn spawn_actor<'r>(&'r self) -> Actor<'r>{
        Actor{lvl: &'r self.lvl}
    }
}
impl<'self> GameManager <'self> {
    pub fn new() -> GameManager{
        GameManager {actors: ~[], actor_controller: ActorController{lvl: Level}}
    }
}
fn main() {
    let mut gm = GameManager::new();

    let actor1 = gm.actor_controller.spawn_actor();

    gm.actors.push(actor1);


}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have an immutable borrow to gm inside Actor and can't modify it as long as it exists.

You can change it into a const borrow as in :

```
struct Actor<'self>{
    lvl: &'self const Level
}
```

But I'm not sure it will still exists on next rust releases. (They try to get rid of it in the compiler at least)

Another alternative would be to use @-pointers. You won't have any borrow issue then :)

Edit : Here's the whole code with const that compiles

```
struct Level;

pub struct GameManager<'self>{
    lvl: Level,
    actors: ~[Actor<'self>]
}
struct Actor<'self>{
    lvl: &'self const Level
}
impl<'self> GameManager <'self> {
    pub fn new() -> GameManager{
        GameManager {lvl: Level,actors: ~[]}
    }
    fn spawn_actor<'r>(&'r const self) -> Actor<'r>{
        Actor{lvl: &'r const self.lvl}
    }
}
fn main() {
    let mut gm = GameManager::new();

    let mut actor1 = gm.spawn_actor();

    gm.actors.push(actor1);
}
```

Comment: I get exactly the same error msg with "const" and I really don't want to use @ because everything is shared in one scope. :(

Comment: [There's a bug to remove `const`,](https://github.com/mozilla/rust/issues/7700), so this is likely to stop working at some point.

Comment: What would be best practice in this case then, using managed or raw pointers to allow multiple references ? How would one implements 2 objects seeing each other using linear types without const and still being able to mutate it ? I've come across this problem a couple of time and didn't find any easy solution :/

Comment: @vcque I think the only thing we can do is to encapsulate a bit more, see my solution below.